# WorkItem Tracking error when performing clone operation in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

Today I received an error when trying to clone test plans in Azure DevOps web portal. 
Steps:

1. In Visual Studio, I select the Test Case option
2. I find the Test Plan I want to clone, select it , and then select the "Clone test plan" button.
3. In the "Clone Test Plan" window, accept all defaults and click Clone.

Result: an error is received: "Clone operation encountered a WorkItem Tracking error while processing test case xxxx. Retry the operation. Error details: TF51535: Cannot find field 25."

It is extremely unfortunate that this issue happened today while I am trying to clone a large test plan. I will have to manually copy the hundreds of tests in order to have the new test plan ready for Monday morning.

Answer (score 1):

This is an indication that someone removed a field from work item configuration that was represented by `25`.  It's more of an issue of clean-up not being done when fields are removed.  See more about [this error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/260665/tf51535-in-client-tf400645-in-web-after-deleting-a.html) on Microsoft's Developer Community.

This [other item in the community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/476709/clone-test-plan-fails.html) suggests a different problem when using a particular extension and a fix has been supplied.